# Tri bike or track bike?

Tags: road-bike, triathlon, track-racing

I am in the verge of buying an [Argon18](http://www.argon18bike.com/bikes/triathlon-tt.html) [E-114](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/category/bikes/time-trial-triathlon/product/review-argon-18-e-114-11-frame-fork-and-stem-39991/).

Can anyone please advise me as to whether it is a track or a triathlon bike?

Looking at the hub spacing on the rear and the bb height it seems to be a track bike. The seller says it is a tri bike.

Comment: Brakes and derailleurs are a pretty strong hint, track bikes do not have either. But, why are you buying an expensive bike if you even don't know what it is for?

Comment: A seller who doesn't know much about the bike is a red flag for a stolen bike. I'd run the serial number through BikeIndex.com and some of the other bike registries. It'd suck if you find out later that it was stolen and it gets returned without compensation to the original owner.

Comment: The website you link to *says* it's a Tri bike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer has uploaded a video for the E114 stating that it is a triathlon bike.

Argon18 Video on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Argon 18 website](http://www.argon18bike.com/bikes/triathlon-tt.html) it is almost certainly a triathlon bike. The other E series bikes are listed in the triathlon/time trial section, and their track bikes use a different naming scheme. [The reviews I found](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/category/bikes/time-trial-triathlon/product/review-argon-18-e-114-11-frame-fork-and-stem-39991/) also call it a triathlon bike. Then there are the brakes and derailers (and triathlon bars) mentioned by @ojs.

Given the difference between [track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_cycling) and [triathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triathlon) riding and the rather obvious differences between bikes meant for each discipline (derailers vs. no derailers for starters) it seems quite odd that the seller can't tell you what type of bike it is.
I'd second @RoboKaren's suggestion that you check it out as a possible stolen bike.